# How can I fill in a Sharepoint List edit form offline using Windows Mobile 5.0 Quickly?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-5.0

I need a method for a user to quickly enter info using a Handheld Symbol MC9090 scanner running windows Mobile 5.0 from a power off state

Currently it takes approx 1 min from power off state for user to enter data into a sharepoint list. I need to get the time down to seconds. 
It takes approx 30secs for handheld to establish wireless connection and another 30 seconds for user to connect to server

Currently we have Symbol MC9090 scanners running windows Mobile 5.0. The user has to use terminal services to connect to a server were they then enter info. We use terminal services because mobile internet explorer doesn't work well with sharepoint forms we are using and is slow.

I have yet to find an easy method to create custom mobile forms for sharepoint lists.

Is it possible to create an app that would collect data on the mobile and when the wireless connection was active sync the local data with the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delay is all to do with network connections and starting up terminal services.

You could write a program for your mobile devices to enter and store information and later sync with SharePoint via its web services.

This gives an example of how to use the web services

- http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/3104621

This is the official documentation for the web services

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390.aspx

How to get started with windows mobile

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/default.aspx